# ld: framework not found "CustomFrameworkName"

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode7-beta3

I am trying to create a Custom Framework following this url 
http://www.makeandbuild.com/blog/post/watchkit-with-shared-core-data

However When I am creating a custom framework called "DataStore"

> Ld /Users/harshadkhedekar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestScanner-fsxgnfdpdqvxdlasdbbjeurajlkj/Build/Intermediates/TestScanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestScanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestScanner normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/harshadkhedekar/Documents/Harshad/Projects/Sandvik/Start Value/17 Aug"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta 3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode-beta\ 3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta\ 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/harshadkhedekar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestScanner-fsxgnfdpdqvxdlasdbbjeurajlkj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/harshadkhedekar/Documents/Harshad/Projects/Sandvik/Start\ Value/17\ Aug/TestScanner/RedLaserSDK -F/Users/harshadkhedekar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestScanner-fsxgnfdpdqvxdlasdbbjeurajlkj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/harshadkhedekar/Documents/Harshad/Projects/Sandvik/Start\ Value/17\ Aug/DataStore -filelist /Users/harshadkhedekar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestScanner-fsxgnfdpdqvxdlasdbbjeurajlkj/Build/Intermediates/TestScanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestScanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestScanner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker "" -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libstdc++ -framework CoreLocation -framework Security -framework OpenGLES -liconv -framework Foundation -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -lRedLaserSDK_arm64 -framework DataStore -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/harshadkhedekar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestScanner-fsxgnfdpdqvxdlasdbbjeurajlkj/Build/Intermediates/TestScanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestScanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestScanner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/harshadkhedekar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestScanner-fsxgnfdpdqvxdlasdbbjeurajlkj/Build/Intermediates/TestScanner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestScanner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TestScanner
>
> ld: framework not found DataStore
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried adding the Framework Search paths to "$(SRCROOT)/DataStore" and "$(inherited)". But still I am this issue is not fixed. Can I know the root cause of this issue. When I create a blank project and add custom framework to it, the blank project is build successfully. I am using Xcode 7 Beta 3 version.
Thanks